# How can I pass a variable from slot to its layout in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 8 and I can't find a way to solve this problem.

> I have a app-layout like this:

```html
<!-- ./app-layout.blade.php -->

<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <livewire:create-suggestion />
    {{ $slot }}
  </body>
</html>
```

> And this view uses the app-layout:

```html
<!-- ./index.blade.php -->

<x-app-layout>
    ...
</x-app-layout>
```

> In controller, I pass a variable to index view:

```
public function index() {
    return view('index', ['variable', '$variable']);
}
```

> How can I pass this variable to the app-layout? Because I also want to
> use this in the create-suggestion livewire component.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass any variable attribute to the layout like so:

`<x-layout :myvariable=$myvariable>`

or static attribute values like so

`<x-layout myvariable="This is a string">`

and retrieve it in the `layout.blade.php` like so:

`{{ $attributes['myvariable'] }}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this. edit your `index.blade.php`

```
@extends('app-layout', ['variable' => $variable])

...
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!
But, I have to change the way using layout to template inheritance.

Comment: @iamphonghg Great!

Comment: I hope there is a way to solve the problem that still using the layout component.

Comment: @iamphonghg of course there is! Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First off I beleive the App Layout will have access to whatever is passed by the view function. But if I am wrong or you wish to pass any custom variable whatsoever using the Layout syntaxt as opposed to template inheritance the way would be: (I came cross your question having a problem passing a static string for my HTML page title and no solution worked until I found this)

```
<x-app-layout>
    <x-slot:variable>{{$variable}}</x-slot>
</x-app-layout>
```

However your issue is you are using Livewire and livewire is not simply just a view! Laravel Intentionally makes Livewire independent from the rest of the page. You would have to either pass it in PHP as param during mount which will only be accessible if set during the mount function() in \App\HTTP\LiveWire\createSuggestion.php

```
@livewire("create-suggestion",[ $variable])
```

Or ideally you have your javascript use the $emit feature to pass the element to the livewire listener all handled via Livewire. It seems to me you are using Livewire for something that you should simply only use Blade/Views:

```
@include("create-suggestion");
```